# Como bloquear uma tag <a> com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Eu tenho um Step by Step que preciso cancelar a passagem para a proxima pagina...

Esse é o meu codigo :

```
  var nome = document.getElementById('nome').value;
  var resposta = true;
  if(nome == ''){

    var resposta = false;

  }
        if(resposta == false){

         //desabilitar <a>

        }else{

          //habilitar <a>
                 
        }
//esse é o meu link reponsavel por passar o step
<a href="#next" id="proximonext"  role="menuitem" >Proximo</a>
```

imagens ilustrativas
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

se eu não fui claro , por favor não feche o meu post , é só perguntar que eu dou mais detalhes... obrigado!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi o "desabilitar" corretamente, você pode fazer o seguinte:

`$("#proximonext").attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');`

E se a variável `resposta` tiver `true` como valor, substitua o `'javascript:void(0)'` pelo link desejado.

Para entender o uso do `void` com manipulação do atributo `href` dentro do JavaScript, recomendo a leitura da [Documentação da Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void).

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: vou tentar amigo!

Comment: Funcionou !! Obrigado mesmo!!

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar. E como a resposta te ajudou, por favor, marque-a como "melhor resposta" se possível.